# If $f(x+y)=f(x)u(y)+f(y)$ for some $f$ monotonic, find all such $u$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Find all functions $u:R\rightarrow{R}$ for which there exists a
> strictly monotonic function $f:R\rightarrow{R}$ such that
> $f(x+y)=f(x)u(y)+f(y)$  for all $x,y\in{\mathbb{R}}$

Let $P(x,y)$ be the assertion of f.e as usual. Let the strictly monotonic property be shown as $(\clubsuit)$. Clearly $u(x) \neq 0$ and $f$ is injective.
\begin{align*}
    &P(0,x):f(0)u(x)=0  \stackrel{(\clubsuit)}{\Rightarrow} f(0)=0 \\
    &P(x,0): f(x)=f(x)u(0) \stackrel{(\clubsuit)}{\Rightarrow} u(0)=1 \\ 
    &P(-x,x): f(-x)u(x)+f(x)=0 \Rightarrow  u(x) = \frac{ -f(x)}{f(-x)} \qquad &(\spadesuit) \\
    &P(x,y)-P(y,x)= f(x)\big(u(y)-1 \big)= f(y)\big( u(x)-1 \big)  \Rightarrow \frac{f(x)}{f(y)}= \frac{u(x)-1}{u(y)-1} &\qquad (1)
  \end{align*}
Assume $u(a)=1$ for some $a \neq 0$. By $(\clubsuit)$ if $x \neq 0$  in $(\spadesuit)$ we have $f(x) \neq f(-x)$. if $-f(x)=f(-x)$, or that is, $f$ is odd function, analyzing $P(-x,x)$ once more yields
$$ f(x) \big( -u(x)+1\big)=0$$
Since $f$ is obviously not constant, we must have $u(x)=1$ which is a clear solution. Hence, for sake of finding another solutions, assume $u(a)=1$ only if $a=0$.

Observe $(1)$ carefully. $f(x)$ increases as same as $u(x)-1$, or in other words $u'(x)= f'(x)$  i.e  if there exist another solution $u$, then $f(x)=u(x)+c$ for some constant satisfishes the problem. In fact, $f'(x)=g'(x)$ is a very well known problem for  real numbers, which as the only solution (IFF) $f(x)=g(x)+c$ for some constant $c$.
Then, $u(x)$ is also strictly monotonic function, which is obvious why. And, we can even find what our constant is, since $u(0)=1$ and $f(0)=0$, $c=-1$. Then we can rewrite our f.e as
$$u(x+y)= u(x)u(y)$$

Which is a well known problem and the only solutions are $u(x)=e^{ax}$ for some parameter $a$ which indeed works, hence we are done.

My problem: The problem about my solution is $f'(x)=g'(x)$ part.I am not sure but I think that $f,u$ being not continous or differentiable doesn't change anything ( still, $f,u$ is almost differentiable since they are monotonic, even if our claim is wrong, it must be true on every value except  set of measure $0$), the fact that $(1)$ is true for all $x$ must imply there are some $f$ such that $f(x)+1=u(x)$, am I wrong? If I am wrong, is it possible that I can prove $f,u$ is continous and differentiable? Is it possible to fix my solution? Can someone help please? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you differentiate at all... $(1)$ implies that for $u(x)\not\equiv 1$,  $f(x)=bu(x)-b$ and so $u(x)$ must be strictly monotonic, and just plugging to original equation gives $bu(x+y)=bu(x)u(y)$, and since $b\neq 0$ you have $u(x+y)=u(x)u(y)$ with $u$ strictly monotonic and so $u(x)=e^{ax}$ follows

Comment: uh hmmm, I didn't even see that I guess I overcomplicated things, thanks